# Random values generating

Tags: java, arrays, methods, random

Generating random values when using an array.

Comment: PetName is an array.  You need to refer to a specific element in an array.  Having said that, I don't know that I see why you need an array.

Comment: Initially I didn't have an array in the code, and simply used a string to store a petname. But I need to have multiple pet's now whose names are stored in an array per my assignment's criteria 

"As above but the program now allows multiple alien pets each with an array recording its
emotional state. Another array records each pet’s name."

Comment: I think you've posted the wrong code ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the array index to fetch the value.

Just as you are storing the value in the array using indexes using `petName[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your pet called?");`, you need to retrieve values from the array using  Use `petName[index]`

Answer (score 0):

System.out.println("Oh cool, " + petName[i] + " is a very unique name!");

Comment: I've made that change within the first method. from petName to petName[i].  But when I try to do it in the second method, I get a cannot be resolved to a variable error.

Answer (score 0):

Petname is an string array, so you need to use `petname[0]` to get the name of the pet.

But since a pet only has one name, I think it would be better to use a simple String as the pet's name.